# Database version number location

Tags: sql-server, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm working on developing YAML build and deploy pipelines for dacpacs built from Visual Studio database projects , and one of the requirements is version numbers.  In my research, I've found two ways we might want to implement it:

Extended Properties via the add- and updateextendedproperty stored procedures.

sysdac_instances via setting the DacVersion when the .dacpac is built and using the RegisterDataTierAppliction flag when the dacpac is deployed.

Is one of these methods preferred over the other?  Am I trying to compare apples to oranges?  Is there a third way to store database versions that I haven't found?  Is there a DevOps or DBA best practice that I don't know and should be following?

Comment: If you're using SSDT/DACPACs for deployment, then versioning in this way makes the most sense (and the way I encourage).

Comment: Edited with more specifics.  We are using .dacpacs and Visual Studio database projects.  Which method were you referring to?  The sysdac_instances?

Comment: The `RegisterDataTierAppliction` approach: <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.dacdeployoptions.registerdatatierapplication?view=sql-dacfx-150#Microsoft_SqlServer_Dac_DacDeployOptions_RegisterDataTierApplication>